# Is there any Azure service similar to AWS systems manager(SSM)?

Tags: node.js, azure, sdk

AWS-SDK provides SSM send command to send any powershell script to EC2 instance. Is there any module in Azure-sdk that I can use to send powershell scripts to VM.

Comment: You can use VM Extensions for such scenario.
You can create an extension on Portal, in ARM template or through Azure CLI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/extension?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-extension-set

Comment: This is I believe what you are looking for - Create a VM extension using node.js Azure SDK. Method beginCreateOrUpdate(string, string, string, VirtualMachineExtension, Object)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-arm-compute/virtualmachineextensions?view=azure-node-latest#begincreateorupdate-string--string--string--virtualmachineextension--object-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Update the VMs as in AWS SSM we can use [Azure Update Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-update-management) for VMs. It uses azure automation account.

- For running commands inside VMs [Run Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command) operation
- Hybrid Connection Azure [Automation Hybrid Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker)
- Inventory - [Azure VM Inventory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-vm-inventory)

Comment: The minimum time to run a script using run command is about 20 seconds and it has many other restrictions.

Comment: Then you can use automation account to run script in VMs too

Comment: Use this below linked PowerShell Runbook to upload the script and run against the VMs
https://tech.xenit.se/azure-automation-running-scripts-locally-vm-runbooks/

And other option is we can use [custom script extension] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows) to run commands inside a VM.